# how to set up a spyder shortcut for middle mouse click on linux

Tags: spyder

I started using spyder a while ago and I would like to find or define a middle-mouse-click shortcut, which click has the effect of pasting what was last selected right where the cursor is, at least on Linux (the analog of Ctrl-Y in emacs).

But i cannot find an already defined shortcut for this nor am i able to define new shortcuts in spyder. The version I am using is spyder-3.0.0.

Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

Note: this is not about select + copy (Ctrl-C) followed by pasting (Ctrl-V), but about select only followed by yanking what was selected (from spyder editor or elsewhere). This works on linux with emacs using Ctrl-Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*)

> Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

No, it's not possible, sorry. We don't define a customizable shortcut for middle-mouse-click that you can't override with your own operation.